# Use of MPI_COMM_SELF

Tags: c, mpi, communicator

I've discovered an MPI communicator called MPI_COMM_SELF. The problem is, I don't know, when is it useful. It appears to me, that just every process "thinks" about itself as root.

Could you explain me how does `MPI_COMM_SELF` exactly work and in which situations is it useful?

I've found [this](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/moved.MPI/paper_07.pdf) slide-show, but the communicator is only briefly mentioned there.

---

I've tried this "Hello, world" example and all processes returned 0 as their PID.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_SELF, &world_rank);

    printf("Hello, my PID is %d!\n",
            world_rank);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm puzzled why you haven't just googled this. [This page](http://www.softeng.rl.ac.uk/st/archive/SoftEng/SESP/Publications/paraio/paraio/node54.html) has a case where MPI_COMM_SELF is useful.

Comment: @aakashjain I've somehow missed it. But now I'm puzzled :-) Couldn't it be replaced just by if-elseif-else statement in this case? (reading/writing to multiple files at once)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An MPI communicator is two pieces of information:  a collection of processes, and a context for that collection.   The defaulit communicators are MPI_COMM_WORLD -- every process -- and MPI_COMM_SELF -- just one process.

you can make more communicators with all, one, or some processes.

Why is context important?   think libraries.  A library using MPI could conflict with the client of that library, except a library will duplicate the communicator and thereby create a context where the library can communicate and never need to worry about what the client is doing.

MPI_COMM_SELF is a single process.  If you call a collective routine, all processes in the communicator must participate.

MPI_COMM_SELF is particularly  useful to MPI-IO routines, but only if you want "file per process".  If you are sharing a file with multiple MPI processes (and you probably should do so), use a communicator encompassing those MPI processes.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the IO-related use of `MPI_COMM_SELF`, there are two more described in the MPI standard.

One particular use of `MPI_COMM_SELF` is to have user functions called during the finalisation of the MPI library, very similar to the `atexit()` mechanism in C. In fact, one cannot reliably use the `atexit()` mechanism in MPI programs since the MPI implementations are not required to return from `MPI_Finalize()` except in rank 0 and therefore another mechanism is needed (also, Fortran doesn't have an equivalent of `atexit()` at all). Fortunately, MPI provides a caching mechanism that allows portable association of arbitrary attributes to some MPI objects, namely communicators, windows and datatypes, which is mainly useful when writing portable libraries. Each attribute has a set of copy and delete callbacks that get called each time a certain event happens, for example when an attribute gets copied as a result of the duplication of a communicator. The standard does not give any guarantee on the order in which all MPI objects get destroyed during `MPI_Finalize()` but it guarantees that `MPI_COMM_SELF` is the first one to get destroyed. So attaching an attribute with a delete callback to `MPI_COMM_SELF` will trigger the callback right after the call to `MPI_Finalize()`.

Another use of `MPI_COMM_SELF` is with the client/server mechanism of MPI. If you have an MPI job and want one of the ranks to receive a client connection from a separate MPI job, you must use `MPI_COMM_SELF` since `MPI_Comm_accept()` is a collective call.